# Load template file without a post type

Tags: templates, template-hierarchy

Is there a way of loading a template file without having a post? I'm loading set of data via an API. Set up my index page but having a brain freeze with single template files as these posts are not in the WP registry/database.

```
// Template files
events-index.php
events-single.php
```

Events index:

```
 <?php $events = $api_data // Data retrieved from API

   if ( $upcoming_events->have_posts() ) :
     while ( $upcoming_events->have_posts() ) : $upcoming_events->the_post();

     $custom_link = sanitize_title( get_the_title() );
     $custom_link = rtrim($custom_link, '/');
     $custom_link .= '?' . get_the_ID(); ?>

     <a href="<?php echo $custom_link; ?>">
     // This link to a custom template file
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup a custom rewrite rule using [add_rewrite_rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) and send these requests to a custom page.

Your URL structure could be `/index-page/single-event-slug` The rule would point all of the single events to a separate page where you can then set your template `events-single.php`.

Another option is to pass the events in as a query `/index-page?event=single-event-slug` or `/index-page?event=123`. You'd need to register this parameter with [add_query_arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) and then change your index template to use the event template via the [template_include](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) hook.

Comment: Thanks. Wrote a snippet which works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
function prefix_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'eid';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'prefix_register_query_var' );
function prefix_rewrite_templates() {
    if ( get_query_var( 'eid' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
            return get_template_directory() . '/events-single.php';
        });
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'prefix_rewrite_templates' );
```

Add the `$var` to the URL in the loop:

```
$url = add_query_arg( array(
    'eid' => get_the_ID(),
) );
```